# How to change the buttons in a JOptionPane using AspectJ

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I need to change the behavior of every JButton in an application (it's a research project). We felt that the best way to change all of the buttons using an aspect since it would keep it clean--we wouldn't have to change all 262 instances to a new type. We have run into a snag. The aspect that we have written does not modify the buttons in a JOptionPane like it does for every other button in our project. Here is the advice that I have:

```
after() returning(JButton button): call(*.new(..)) || call(* newInstance(..)) {
    init(button);
}
```

This matches every other constructor of JButton, but it seems to be missing the one used by JOptionPane. How can I access their creation? I'm still new at AOP, so maybe this isn't even possible to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think AspectJ ignores the `javax` package by default. Since the option pane buttons are created in the look and feel code (see `BasicOptionPaneUI.ButtonFactory` in the `javax.swing.plaf.basic` package for example), that might be why it's being ignored. Maybe look at changing the configuration options to allow/include the javax package?

Comment: That explanation surely makes sense. I'll have to try to figure out how I can make it weave into the `javax` package tomorrow when I go in. Thanks for the tip!